# How do I separate a string like this line by line?

Tags: java, string

I have a string that I want to read line by line:

```
"8688642986379252 Michael_Thompson 816 2500.0
8904000405634912 Barbara_Martin
8610835007621519 Charles_Jackson 1019 52800.0"
```

It goes on on and on in that format.

I tried separating it using for loops, charAt() and reducing the size of the string using substring() but I failed miserably.

I'm sure it's something simple but I just can't get it. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there newlines between the lines that you want to separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Scanner` to read line by line using `nextLine`. Then, split every `String` by blank space`" "`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringWithBreaklines);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] content = line.split(" ");
    //do what you want/need with content
}
```

If the `String` is inside a file, then read the file directly using `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
//same code as above...
```

Comment: Actually, this all worked, minus the String[] content part, which I didn't end up needing. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `str.split("\n")`.  It will produce an array of strings, one index for each line.  This is assuming you can read the whole thing into a string.  If the input is large, this won't work.

Comment: What if is windows line separated `"\r\n"`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: @user3580294 how can you be sure the file uses the same line separator that the current underlying OS you're working with?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Then split on `"(\n|\r\n)"`?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the the string is actually from a text file that the user submits. When I download and actually open the text file using regular notepad on my computer the string actually looks like one continuous line. So I don't think/and not sure that each line is separated by ("\n") like it shows in my original post.

Comment: @PeacefulCalamity then it would be better to open the file directly using `Scanner`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, and I feel bad for being difficult, but the project indicates that I absolutely need to return a only one string value per line (so something like String k would be the first line in my original post, "8688642986379252 Michael_Thompson 816 2500.0" ) The scanner that reads the .txt file from the user is actually in main, and then it sends that text file to a another method that takes it as one continuous string. And that's the method I'm trying to create, the method taking the continuous string. I'm not so great at explaining this, but maybe that clears it up...

Comment: @PeacefulCalamity Hmmm.... You aren't allowed to use `Scanner.nextLine()` and send the method a `String[]`? If not, you can always use `str.split("(\n|\r\n)")`, which *should* cover the newlines used by *nix and Windows, assuming the regex is right.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `java.util.Scanner` class to read tokens one by one.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html